# Anonymous user can't see my uploaded files on vsftpd

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, sftp, ubuntu-18.04, vsftpd

I have a directory `/var/ftp/pub` with `drwxr--r--` permissions for ftpuser. I put my files in there, but anonymous account can not see them. The files themselves have `-rw-r--r--` permissions.

It could be permissions issue, however I tried various permission codes and none worked. It is probably unrelated to connection, since if I use Total Commander, it just shows empty directory. If I access it through browser it says "ERR_FTP_FAILED". Ftpuser can see the files just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, there's one permission I didn't try - 755.

`sudo chmod 755 /var/ftp/pub` did the trick.